# jQuery UI tabs and jQuery functions on a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

When page containing jquery-ui-tabs at the top loads for the first time, jquery elements bellow the tabs do work (e.g. for deleting or editing  table rows on the page).. but when another tab gets clicked and the previous tab gets clicked again, the jquery functions on the page (the ones for deleting or editing) don't work anymore.

?

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can look at what might be going wrong in detail?

Answer (score 1):

look at using jquery live for your events. http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('#deleteButton').live('click', function(){
    //do delete
});

$('#editButton').live('click', function(){
    //do edit
});
```

this ensures the events stay registered for all current and future instances.